# Writing the path of the uploaded pictures in database

Tags: c#, image, upload, path, dataset

This is my image uploader that uploads straight to the folder i want including thumbnails.
So what i want to do is to write for each time i upload a picture it always write it's path in my database table for example: here is the picture how i want it to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHoO.jpg

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("././Data/Normal/") + fileName);
        System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(MapPath("././Data/Normal/") + FileUpload1.FileName);

        System.Drawing.Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(680, 450, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        bmp1.Save(MapPath("././Data/Thumbnails/") + FileUpload1.FileName);

    }

 PhotoTableAdapter PhotoInfo = new PhotoTableAdapter();
PhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,TextBox4.Text);
}
```

After the TextBox4.Text, i should add something to write the path for this table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Vwh.jpg
It would be great if i can get some help thank you

Comment: you can send filename as last parameter to InserPhoto function.

Comment: I wish i knew how to do it... i am still learning, so that's why i am here :)-

Comment: you want anything more like how to insert in database?

Comment: Yeah how to insert that path link to the database, please check the two picture and you will understand :D

Comment: it would be easy if you can share how you are inserting TextBox values into database so that i will edit that and post .

Comment: could you please share the InsertPhoto() function code?

Comment: Photoinfo.insertphoto that's how i insert my data using dataset.

Comment: sorry i didnt see yeah that is an adapter. imean PhotoTableAdapter Class.

Comment: I  haven't use any class objects yet this is straight to one table so i thought i wouldn't need it

Comment: i think you are using DataModel concept for inserting data so you need to Change the input parameters for PhotoTableAdapter class, you can find that please check it.

Comment: INSERT INTO Photo
                         (Name, Description, Caption, TagID, Path_Thumbnail, Path_L)
VALUES        (@Name,@Description,@Caption,@TagID,@Path_Thumbnail,@Path_L)

Comment: Okay you have to set the values for those parameters could you please explore little more? and show me how you are adding values to those parameters.

Comment: PhotoTableAdapter PhotoInfo = new PhotoTableAdapter();
PhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,TextBox4.Text, and now the path for thembnail and than for the path L );

Comment: goto this block ->INSERT INTO Photo (Name, Description, Caption, TagID, Path_Thumbnail, Path_L) VALUES (@Name,@Description,@Caption,@TagID,@Path_Thumbnail,@Path_L) and explore more and see what other statements you could find and let me know

Comment: That's the only statements needed. there is nothing more the is not active so it wouldn't even make any problem the statement i wrote is the one.

Comment: In all they are 6 arguments, 4 already works and than just the last two for the path link tex (Path_Thumbnail and Path_L)

Comment: Okay fine, please tell me path for both image and thumbnail are same right?

Comment: They are not the same :  one ././Data/Thumbnails/ and the other ././Data/Normal/

So basically when you upload a picture it uploads it in the folder and write it path in it's column .

As you can see in my uploadfile1 code how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm assuming that you have updated your `DataModel` to get the newly added columns in `Database` they are `Path_Thumbnail`,`Path_L`

if you have updated your `DataModel` you will get following uodated `Query` in your Model :

```
INSERT INTO Photo (Name, Description, Caption, TagID, Path_Thumbnail, Path_L) VALUES (@Name,@Description,@Caption,@TagID,@Path_Thumbnail,@Path_L);
```

Now while sending the Data to Insert Command add the both `ThumbnailPath` and `ImagePath` sothat along with normal feilds both images paths will be saved into `Database`.

**Replace this:**

```
PhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,TextBox4.Text);
```

**With following:**

```
PhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,TextBox4.Text,Server.MapPath("././Data/Thumbnails/") + FileUpload1.FileName,Server.MapPath("././Data/Normal/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

if you want to save only Relative Path of the images(only path from project folders) use following code:

```
PhotoInfo.InsertPhoto(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,TextBox4.Text,"././Data/Thumbnails/" + FileUpload1.FileName,"././Data/Normal/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: filepath,filepath i added it but the problem it says "The Name "filepath" does not exist in the current context

Comment: i have edited my answer by taking two different values for thumbnail and image it works perfectly now please check it.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly good but it write the whole path from the windows... like this :C:\Users\SADSC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\Dashboard\Photo\Data\Thumbnails\beautiful.png

Now my question would it always be like that or is it because i am just using local host with database ?

Comment: so you don't want to save whole path? you want to save for example "././Data/Normal/"myimage.jpg" right?

Comment: Yeah but still loads it like you seen the first picture in my question ? That's how i want it to look like to avoid the issues in the future...

Comment: i have edited my answer to save only relative paths (paths from project folders) please check it.